# How many votes does a political party in Indonesia need to have a seat in parliement?

Tags: indonesia

I've heard that the parliamentary treshold is 2%.

However, it doesn't seem to make sense to me. There are around 500 people in DPR in Indonesia.

So parliamentary treshold should be 100%/500 =.2%

My bro angrily explains about some winner takes all system that I do not quite understand and as far as I know is NOT implemented in Indonesia (unlike in US).

So what's going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indonesian_legislative_election,_2014), the threshold is actually 3.5%.

Your logic is mistaken.  Your calculation is based on the assumption that a party should be allowed into the DPR if it gets enough votes for 1 candidate across the whole of Indonesia.  In fact, the threshold is set so that they need to get enough votes for 17 members.  This reduces the problem of having a legislature with lots of very small parties (the small parties tend to have disproportionate influence).

Note that because the election is actually done proportionally within each district (*and* voters can vote for individual candidates), the eventual numbers may still not be exact.

Comment: is parliamentary threshold common in democracy?

Comment: @user4951 It is common in democracies that use some sort of proportional representation.  It is not needed in democracies that use "first past the post" - line the UK and USA.  In those countries there is a very strong tendency for there to be two very dominant parties (it is quite easy to get 10% of the vote in every constituency and none of the seats).

Comment: @user4951 https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electoral_system_of_Germany if you scroll to the voting system section you can see the German Second vote, the PR bit requires a party reach a 5% threshold.